# ECG compliance: How to do?

Tags: magento-1, best-practice, coding-standards, magento-ecg

There is something like a `coding standard` for **Magento 1**, called `ECG` where numerous things should be avoided or methods that should not be used.

Let's try to create a list that covers all cases that are throwing "errors" or "warning" in your code.

Below you'll find a list with all possible warnings. I'll update this post at regular intervals and link to given and upvoted answers.

*Note:* please try to avoid duplicate answers ;)

Download: https://github.com/magento-ecg/coding-standard

---

## ECG Sniffs

**Classes**

> **[Mysql4](https://github.com/magento-ecg/coding-standard/blob/master/Ecg/Sniffs/Classes/Mysql4Sniff.php)**
>
> Mysql4 classes are obsolete.

- [How to handle deprecated “Mysql4” classes when rewriting resource models](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/3796/46249)
- [Magento 1.9 module oddly breaking when changing resource folder from Mysql4 to Resource](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/60351/magento-1-9-module-oddly-breaking-when-changing-resource-folder-from-mysql4-to-r)

> **[Object Instantiation](https://github.com/magento-ecg/coding-standard/blob/master/Ecg/Sniffs/Classes/ObjectInstantiationSniff.php)**
>
> Direct object instantiation (class %s) is discouraged in Magento.

```
protected $disallowedClassPrefixes = array(
    'Mage_',
    'Enterprise_',
);
```

...

**PHP**

> **[Goto](https://github.com/magento-ecg/coding-standard/blob/master/Ecg/Sniffs/PHP/GotoSniff.php)**
>
> Use of goto is discouraged.

...

> **[Namespace](https://github.com/magento-ecg/coding-standard/blob/master/Ecg/Sniffs/PHP/NamespaceSniff.php)**
>
> Namespace for "'.$exceptionClassName.'" class is not specified.

...

> **[Private Class Member](https://github.com/magento-ecg/coding-standard/blob/master/Ecg/Sniffs/PHP/PrivateClassMemberSniff.php)**
>
> Private class member detected.

...

> **[Var](https://github.com/magento-ecg/coding-standard/blob/master/Ecg/Sniffs/PHP/VarSniff.php)**
>
> Private class member detected.

...

**Performance**

> **[Collection Count](https://github.com/magento-ecg/coding-standard/blob/master/Ecg/Sniffs/Performance/CollectionCountSniff.php)**
>
> Unnecessary loading of a Magento data collection. Use the getSize() method instead.

- [How to check if a collection has items?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/179035/46249)

> **[FetchAll](https://github.com/magento-ecg/coding-standard/blob/master/Ecg/Sniffs/Performance/FetchAllSniff.php)**
>
> fetchAll() can be memory inefficient for large data sets.

...

> **[GetFirstItem](https://github.com/magento-ecg/coding-standard/blob/master/Ecg/Sniffs/Performance/GetFirstItemSniff.php)**
>
> getFirstItem() does not limit the result of collection load to one item.

- GetFirstItem - https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/179309/46249

> **[Loop](https://github.com/magento-ecg/coding-standard/blob/master/Ecg/Sniffs/Performance/LoopSniff.php)**
>
> Array size calculation function %s detected in loop
>
> Model LSD method %s detected in loop
>
> Data load %s method detected in loop

```
protected $countFunctions = array(
    'sizeof',
    'count'
);
protected $modelLsdMethods = array(
    'load',
    'save',
    'delete'
);
```

- load

  - [Find MIN & MAX value of product attribute in a large category](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/179273/find-max-min-product-weight-in-a-large-category/179275#179275)
- ...

**Security**

> **[Acl](https://github.com/magento-ecg/coding-standard/blob/master/Ecg/Sniffs/Security/AclSniff.php)**
>
> Missing the %s() ACL method in the %s class.

```
const PARENT_CLASS_NAME = 'Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action';
const REQUIRED_ACL_METHOD_NAME = '_isAllowed';
```

...

> **[Discouraged Function](https://github.com/magento-ecg/coding-standard/blob/master/Ecg/Sniffs/Security/DiscouragedFunctions.php)**

```
public $forbiddenFunctions = array(
    '^is_dir' => null,
    '^is_file$' => null,
    '^pathinfo$' => null,
);
```

...

> **[Forbidden Function](https://github.com/magento-ecg/coding-standard/blob/master/Ecg/Sniffs/Security/ForbiddenFunctionSniff.php)**

```
public $forbiddenFunctions = array(
    '^assert$' => null,
    '^bind_textdomain_codeset$' => null,
    '^bindtextdomain$' => null,
    '^bz.*$' => null,
    '^call_user_func$' => null,
    '^call_user_func_array$' => null,
    '^chdir$' => null,
    '^chgrp$' => null,
    '^chmod$' => null,
    '^chown$' => null,
    '^chroot$' => null,
    '^com_load_typelib$' => null,
    '^copy$' => null,
    '^create_function$' => null,
    '^curl_.*$' => null,
    '^cyrus_connect$' => null,
    '^dba_.*$' => null,
    '^dbase_.*$' => null,
    '^dbx_.*$' => null,
    '^dcgettext$' => null,
    '^dcngettext$' => null,
    '^dgettext$' => null,
    '^dio_.*$' => null,
    '^dirname$' => null,
    '^dngettext$' => null,
    '^domxml_.*$' => null,
    '^exec$' => null,
    '^fbsql_.*$' => null,
    '^fdf_add_doc_javascript$' => null,
    '^fdf_open$' => null,
    '^fopen$' => null,
    '^fsockopen$' => null,
    '^ftp_.*$' => null,
    '^fwrite$' => null,
    '^gettext$' => null,
    '^gz.*$' => null,
    '^header$' => null,
    '^highlight_file$' => null,
    '^ibase_.*$' => null,
    '^id3_set_tag$' => null,
    '^ifx_.*$' => null,
    '^image.*$' => null,
    '^imap_.*$' => null,
    '^ingres_.*$' => null,
    '^ircg_.*$' => null,
    '^ldap_.*$' => null,
    '^link$' => null,
    '^mail$' => null,
    '^mb_send_mail$' => null,
    '^mkdir$' => null,
    '^move_uploaded_file$' => null,
    '^msession_.*$' => null,
    '^msg_send$' => null,
    '^msql$' => null,
    '^msql_.*$' => null,
    '^mssql_.*$' => null,
    '^mysql_.*$' => null,
    '^odbc_.*$' => null,
    '^opendir$' => null,
    '^openlog$' => null,
    '^ora_.*$' => null,
    '^ovrimos_.*$' => null,
    '^parse_ini_file$' => null,
    '^parse_str$' => null,
    '^parse_url$' => null,
    '^parsekit_compile_string$' => null,
    '^passthru$' => null,
    '^pcntl_.*$' => null,
    '^posix_.*$' => null,
    '^pfpro_.*$' => null,
    '^pfsockopen$' => null,
    '^pg_.*$' => null,
    '^php_check_syntax$' => null,
    '^popen$' => null,
    '^print_r$' => null,
    '^printf$' => null,
    '^proc_open$' => null,
    '^putenv$' => null,
    '^readfile$' => null,
    '^readgzfile$' => null,
    '^readline$' => null,
    '^readlink$' => null,
    '^register_shutdown_function$' => null,
    '^register_tick_function$' => null,
    '^rename$' => null,
    '^rmdir$' => null,
    '^scandir$' => null,
    '^session_.*$' => null,
    '^set_include_path$' => null,
    '^set_ini$' => null,
    '^set_time_limit$' => null,
    '^setcookie$' => null,
    '^setlocale$' => null,
    '^setrawcookie$' => null,
    '^shell_exec$' => null,
    '^sleep$' => null,
    '^socket_.*$' => null,
    '^stream_.*$' => null,
    '^sybase_.*$' => null,
    '^symlink$' => null,
    '^syslog$' => null,
    '^system$' => null,
    '^touch$' => null,
    '^trigger_error$' => null,
    '^unlink$' => null,
    '^vprintf$' => null,
    '^mysqli.*$' => null,
    '^oci_connect$' => null,
    '^oci_pconnect$' => null,
    '^quotemeta$' => null,
    '^sqlite_popen$' => null,
    '^time_nanosleep$' => null,
    '^base64_decode$' => null,
    '^base_convert$' => null,
    '^basename$' => null,
    '^chr$' => null,
    '^convert_cyr_string$' => null,
    '^dba_nextkey$' => null,
    '^dns_get_record$' => null,
    '^extract$' => null,
    '^fdf_.*$' => null,
    '^fget.*$' => null,
    '^fread$' => null,
    '^fflush$' => null,
    '^get_browser$' => null,
    '^get_headers$' => null,
    '^get_meta_tags$' => null,
    '^getallheaders$' => null,
    '^getenv$' => null,
    '^getopt$' => null,
    '^headers_list$' => null,
    '^hebrev$' => null,
    '^hebrevc$' => null,
    '^highlight_string$' => null,
    '^html_entity_decode$' => null,
    '^ibase_blob_import$' => null,
    '^id3_get_tag$' => null,
    '^import_request_variables$' => null,
    '^ircg_nickname_unescape$' => null,
    '^ldap_get_values$' => null,
    '^mb_decode_mimeheader$' => null,
    '^mb_parse_str$' => null,
    '^mcrypt_decrypt$' => null,
    '^mdecrypt_generic$' => null,
    '^msg_receive$' => null,
    '^ngettext$' => null,
    '^ob_get_contents$' => null,
    '^ob_get_flush$' => null,
    '^rawurldecode$' => null,
    '^shm_get_var$' => null,
    '^stripcslashes$' => null,
    '^stripslashes$' => null,
    '^token_get_all$' => null,
    '^unpack$' => null,
    '^convert_uudecode$' => null,
    '^iconv_mime_decode$' => null,
    '^iconv_mime_decode_headers$' => null,
    '^iconv_mime_encode$' => null,
    '^iconv_set_encoding$' => null,
    '^php_strip_whitespace$' => null,
    '^addcslashes$' => null,
    '^addslashes$' => null,
    '^escapeshellarg$' => null,
    '^escapeshellcmd$' => null,
    '^gettype$' => null,
    '^var_dump$' => null,
    '^tempnam$' => null,
    '^realpath$' => null,
    '^linkinfo$' => null,
    '^lstat$' => null,
    '^stat$' => null,
    '^lchgrp$' => null,
    '^lchown$' => null,
    '^show_source$' => null,
    '^is_executable$' => null,
    '^is_link$' => null,
    '^is_readable$' => null,
    '^is_writable$' => null,
    '^is_writeable$' => null,
    '^is_uploaded_file$' => null,
    '^glob$' => null,
    '^ssh2_.*$' => null,
    '^delete$' => null,
    '^file.*$' => null,
);
```

- ...
- curl_: - https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/178642/46249
- file_exists - https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/178641/46249
- ...

> **[Include File](https://github.com/magento-ecg/coding-standard/blob/master/Ecg/Sniffs/Security/IncludeFileSniff.php)**
>
> "%s" statement detected. File manipulations are discouraged.
>
> ... Statement is not a function, no parentheses are required.
>
> ... Passing urls is forbidden.
>
> ... Concatenating is forbidden.
>
> ... Variables inside are insecure.

```
public $urlPattern = '#(https?|ftp)://.*#i';
```

...

> **[Language Construct](https://github.com/magento-ecg/coding-standard/blob/master/Ecg/Sniffs/Security/LanguageConstructSniff.php)**
>
> Incorrect usage of back quote string constant. Back quotes should be always inside strings.
>
> Use of %s language construct is discouraged.

```
    return array(
        T_EXIT,
        T_ECHO,
        T_PRINT,
        T_BACKTICK
    );
```

...

> **[Superglobal](https://github.com/magento-ecg/coding-standard/blob/master/Ecg/Sniffs/Security/SuperglobalSniff.php)**
>
> Direct use of %s Superglobal detected.

```
public $superGlobalErrors = array(
    '$GLOBALS',
    '$_GET',
    '$_POST',
    '$_SESSION',
    '$_REQUEST',
    '$_ENV'
);
public $superGlobalWarning = array(
    '$_FILES',
    '$_COOKIE',
    '$_SERVER',
);
```

**Sql**

> **[Raw Query](https://github.com/magento-ecg/coding-standard/blob/master/Ecg/Sniffs/Sql/RawQuerySniff.php)**
>
> Possible raw SQL statement %s detected

```
public $statements = array(
    'SELECT',
    'UPDATE',
    'INSERT',
    'CREATE',
    'DELETE',
    'ALTER',
    'DROP'
);
public $queryFunctions = array(
    'query',
    'raw_query'
);
```

...

> **[Slow Query](https://github.com/magento-ecg/coding-standard/blob/master/Ecg/Sniffs/Sql/SlowQuerySniff.php)**
>
> Possible slow SQL statement %s detected
>
> Possible slow SQL method %s detected

```
public $adapterMethods = array(
    'group',
    'having',
    'distinct',
    'addLikeEscape',
    'escapeLikeValue',
    'union',
    'orHaving',
);
public $rawStatements = array(
    'GROUP BY',
    'HAVING',
    'DISTINCT',
    'LIKE',
    'UNION',
);
```

...

**Strings**

> **[RegEx](https://github.com/magento-ecg/coding-standard/blob/master/Ecg/Sniffs/Strings/RegExSniff.php)**
>
> Possible executable regular expression in %s. Make sure that the pattern doesn\'t contain "e" modifier

```
public $functions = array(
    'preg_replace',
);
```

...

> **[String Concat](https://github.com/magento-ecg/coding-standard/blob/master/Ecg/Sniffs/Strings/StringConcatSniff.php)**
>
> Use of + operator to concatenate two strings detected

...

> **[String Position](https://github.com/magento-ecg/coding-standard/blob/master/Ecg/Sniffs/Strings/StringPositionSniff.php)**
>
> Identical operator === is not used for testing the return value of %s function

```
public $functions = array(
    'strpos',
    'stripos',
);
```

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php#refsect1-function.strpos-examples
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php#refsect1-function.stripos-examples

---

**Related questions & answers for** [best-practice](/questions/tagged/best-practice)

- [What is faster - getting raw attribute value or use collection?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/148368/what-is-faster-getting-raw-attribute-value-or-use-collection)
- [Magento 1: Performance optimizations to delete entities](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/120132/magento-1-performance-optimizations-to-delete-entities)

Comment: LOL about this post, you wrote almost a doc :)

Comment: @Prince someone else could help a bit to complete this :P

Comment: I don't think so :)

Comment: any alternative for stripcslashes()? @sv3n thanks for such description question  and answers :)

Comment: @KeyurShah No. Either ignore warning or try to avoid "before" :) In wich case you use it? Maybe add this as question?

Comment: Yes  ignoring is best option :) now I am getting error for `session_write_close()` . I am using this function for downloading file(in my module) same like `Mage_Downloadable_DownloadController` in `_processDownload` method @sv3n

Comment: Does anyone has an alternative to addslashes() and/or print_r() ?

Answer (score 6):

## Forbidden Function

### file_exists()

*The use of function file_exists() is forbidden*

**incorrect:**

```
if (!file_exists($filePath)) {
    ...
}
```

**correct:**

```
$io = new Varien_Io_File();
if (!$io->fileExists($filePath)) {
    ...
}
```

or

```
$validatorNot = new Zend_Validate_File_NotExists($path);
if ($validatorNot->isValid($file)) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 6):

## GetFirstItem

*getFirstItem() does not limit the result of collection load to one item.*

**incorrect:**

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
    ->load(41)
    ->getProductCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('weight');

$product = $collection->getFirstItem();
$weight  = $product->getData('weight');
```

**correct:**

Apply limit before grab data.

```
$collection->getSelect()->limit(1)
```

or

```
$collection->setPageSize(1, 1)
```

---

### Expamples:

Collection with 750 products ...

Without limiting before:

- Total Incl. Wall Time (microsec):    2,116,522 microsecs
- Total Incl. CPU (microsecs): 2,101,688 microsecs
- Total Incl. MemUse (bytes):  4,783,504 bytes
- Total Incl. PeakMemUse (bytes):  4,363,112 bytes
- Number of Function Calls:    104,187

With using `getSelect()->limit(1)`:

- Total Incl. Wall Time (microsec):    149,803 microsecs
- Total Incl. CPU (microsecs): 131,405 microsecs
- Total Incl. MemUse (bytes):  2,384,840 bytes
- Total Incl. PeakMemUse (bytes):  1,827,112 bytes
- Number of Function Calls:    5,327

With using `setPageSize(1, 1)`

- Total Incl. Wall Time (microsec):    155,025 microsecs
- Total Incl. CPU (microsecs): 136,191 microsecs
- Total Incl. MemUse (bytes):  2,413,128 bytes
- Total Incl. PeakMemUse (bytes):  1,856,064 bytes
- Number of Function Calls:    5,515

***Note:***

*This warning will still pop up, even if you limit your collection before. To get rid of this message use `$collection->getLastItem()` instead.*

Comment: I am getting  `Data access method LIMIT detected outside of Resource Model` when using limit`

Comment: [Here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/205425/how-to-fix-getfirstitem-does-not-limit-the-result-of-collection-load-to-one-ite) is more details

Comment: Apply limit before grab data means before using load(), or other functions that use it like getFirstItem(), getLastItem(), getItems(), getColumnValues(), getItemsByColumnValue(), getItemByColumnValue(), getItemById(), getIterator(), count(), getSize()

Answer (score 5):

## Forbidden Function

### curl_xyz

*The use of function curl_init(), curl_setopt(), curl_exec(), curl_close() is forbidden*

**incorrect:**

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $request);
curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

**correct:**

```
$options = array(
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $header,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $request
);

$curl = new Varien_Http_Adapter_Curl();
$curl->setOptions($options);
$curl->write(Zend_Http_Client::GET, $url, Zend_Http_Client::HTTP_0);
$response = $curl->read();
$responseBody = Zend_Http_Response::extractBody($response);
$curl->close();
```

Comment: I used above code and it is giving me error `Uncaught Error: Class 'Custom\Rma\Helper\Varien_Http_Adapter_Curl' not found`. How to use the class i found it in vendor but no luck.

Comment: @NitinPawar can you please open a new question? Something seems to be wrong with your code.