# How to check if a collection has items?

Tags: magento-1.9, php, category-products

What does a product that is not found return in terms of Object?

I'm loading a product like the following:

```
$man_collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
    ->load($mProduct)
    ->getProductCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1)
    ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', 4)
    // ->getSelect()->limit(1);
    ->addFieldToFilter(array(
        array('attribute' => 'color', 'eq' => '1049')
    ));
```

Assuming that this specific product with this color code 1049 does not exist in the database, how can I validate it? If I try

```
gettype($man_collection)
```

it still returns Object.  So is there a way to validate this? Like "if product with color code 1049 found proceed, else echo not found"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can check the size of your collection:

```
if ($man_collection->getSize()) {
    //proceed
} else {
    echo "not found";
}
```

Explaination here: [Difference between getSize() and count() on collection](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/4036/difference-between-getsize-and-count-on-collection/4039#4039)

---

**Edit:** tested for 750 products

`$collection->getData()`

- Total Incl. Wall Time (microsec):    67,567 microsecs
- Total Incl. CPU (microsecs): 67,599 microsecs
- Total Incl. MemUse (bytes):  11,719,168 bytes
- Total Incl. PeakMemUse (bytes):  11,648,152 bytes
- Number of Function Calls:    1,047

`$collection->getSize()`

- Total Incl. Wall Time (microsec):    6,371 microsecs
- Total Incl. CPU (microsecs): 4,402 microsecs
- Total Incl. MemUse (bytes):  140,816 bytes
- Total Incl. PeakMemUse (bytes):  96,000 bytes
- Number of Function Calls:    191

`$collection->count()` or `sizeof($collection)`

- Total Incl. Wall Time (microsec): 2,130,568 microsecs
- Total Incl. CPU (microsecs):  2,080,617 microsecs
- Total Incl. MemUse (bytes):   12,899,872 bytes
- Total Incl. PeakMemUse (bytes):   13,002,256 bytes
- Number of Function Calls: 101,073

Comment: Thank you!!! I wanted to see if the Object is empty in terms of data. If it's empty or not it will always return Object. But if it does not contain data the $collection->getData() is the function I was looking for.

Comment: Understand, but use `getData()`only  on (collection) objects, but for collections itself you should go with `getSize()` :)

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question to why you still get the response as an object even if the collection does not contain any products...
A product collection is an object by itself. It contains a lot of things other than an array (not really an array) of products.
It contains references to the tables involved in the query, the query, db connection and a lot others.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this-

```
if($man_collection->Count())
{
   //products found
}
else
{
   // products not found
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Got it.!

It is:

```
if($man_collection->getData())
```