# How to fix 'getFirstItem does not limit the result of collection load to one item` warning?

Tags: magento-1.9

I am validating an extension using [ECG Sniffs](https://github.com/magento-ecg) and I get a warning `'getFirstItem does not limit the result of collection load to one item`

Here is how I am trying to get default configured website.

```
$websites = Mage::getModel('core/website')
                    ->getCollection()
                    ->addFieldToFilter('is_default', 1);
$website = $websites->getFirstItem();
```

Here I try to replace `$websites->getFirstItem()` with `$websites->getSelect()->limit()` as per [a suggestion](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/178640/ecg-compliance-how-to-do) but it gives another warning `Data access method LIMIT detected outside of Resource Model`

Can anybody please help me how to fix the warning?

P.S. I am neither magento nor PHP developer.

Comment: You dont have to replace `$websites->getFirstItem()`. Just add `$websites->getSelect()->limit(1)` before. Btw ... the warning will still appear. If you've limit the query to 1, you can use `getLastItem()` instead.

Comment: @sv3n thanks.  I ended up using `$websites->setPageSize(1, 1)->getLastItem()`

Comment: @sv3n I also get `Data load getParentIdsByChild() method detected in loop` warning. I am fetching parent sku for each product in loop. Here is a reference question https://stackoverflow.com/a/11481143/517483. Any idea?